# vowpal-wabbit: use of multiple passes, holdout, & holdout-period to avoid overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, supervised-learning, vowpalwabbit

I would like to train the binary sigmoidal feedforward network for category classification with following command using awesome `vowpal wabbit tool`:

```
vw --binary --nn 4 train.vw -f category.model
```

And test it:

```
vw --binary -t -i category.model -p test.vw
```

But I had very bad results (comparing to my linear svm estimator).

I found a comment that I should use `Number of Training Passes` argument (`--passes arg`).

So my question is **how to know the count of training passes in order not to get retrained model**?

P.S. should I use `holdout_period` argument? and how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The test command in the question is incorrect. It has no input (`-p ...` indicates output predictions).  Also it is not clear if you want to *test* or *predict* because it says `test` but the command used has `-p ...`

*Test* means you have labeled-data and you're evaluating the quality of your model. Strictly speaking: *predict* means you don't have labels, so you can't actually know how good your predictions are.  Practically, you may also predict on held-out, labeled data (pretending it has no labels by ignoring them) and then evaluate how good these predictions are, since you actually have labels.

Generally:

- if you want to do binary-classification, you should use labels in `{-1, 1}` and use `--loss_function logistic`. `--binary` which is an independent option meaning you want predictions to be binary (giving you less info).
- if you already have a separate test-set with labels, you don't need to holdout.

The holdout mechanism in `vw` was designed to replace the test-set and avoid over-fitting, it is only relevant when multiple passes are used because in a single pass *all* examples are effectively held-out; each next (yet unseen) example is treated as 1) unlabeled for prediction, and as 2) labeled for testing and model-update. IOW: your train-set is effectively also your test-set.

So you can either do **multiple passes on the train-set with no holdout**:

```
 vw --loss_function logistic --nn 4 -c --passes 2 --holdout_off train.vw -f model
```

and then test the model with a separate and labeled, test-set:

```
 vw -t -i model test.vw
```

or do **multiple passes on the same train-set with some hold-out as a test set**.

```
vw --loss_function logistic --nn 4 -c --passes 20 --holdout_period 7 train.vw -f model
```

If you don't have a test-set, and you want to fit-stronger by using multiple-passes, you can ask `vw` to hold-out every `N`th example (the default `N` is 10, but you may override it explicitly using `--holdout_period <N>` as seen above).  In this case, you can specify a higher number of passes because `vw` will automatically do early-termination when the loss on the held-out set starts growing.

You'd notice you hit early termination since `vw` will print something like:

```
passes used = 5
...
average loss = 0.06074 h
```

Indicating that only 5 out of `N` passes were actually used before early stopping, and the error on the held-out subset of example is 0.06074 (the trailing `h` indicates this is held-out loss).

As you can see, the *number of passes*, and the *holdout-period* are completely independent options.

To improve and get more confidence in your model, you could use other optimizations, vary the holdout_period, try other `--nn` args. You may also want to check the `vw-hypersearch` utility (in the `utl` subdirectory) to help find better hyper-parameters.

Here's an example of using `vw-hypersearch` on one of the test-sets included with the source:

```
$ vw-hypersearch 1 20 vw --loss_function logistic --nn % -c --passes 20 --holdout_period 11 test/train-sets/rcv1_small.dat --binary
trying 13 ............. 0.133333 (best)
trying 8 ............. 0.122222 (best)
trying 5 ............. 0.088889 (best)
trying 3 ............. 0.111111
trying 6 ............. 0.1
trying 4 ............. 0.088889 (best)
loss(4) == loss(5): 0.088889
5       0.08888
```

Indicating that either `4` or `5` should be good parameters for `--nn` yielding a loss of 0.08888 on a hold-out subset of 1 in 11 examples.